# Convert [[1, 2], [3, 4]] to [[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4]] without looping

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

```
a = [1, 2]
print a * 2
```

produces `[1, 2, 1, 2]`. Now

```
b = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

Can I convert `b` into `[[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4]]` without looping?

Comment: Why without looping? With looping it's as simple as this: `b = [x * 2 for x in a]`.

Comment: Why the downvotes on this question?  Perhaps it belongs in codegolf, but otherwise I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: @Bill, until there's an explanation for why looping isn't allowed, it's a terribly useless handicap

Comment: @Bill I didn't downvote, but it is tempting since you can't _not_ loop, and therefore the question doesn't really make sense. Yes, you can _hide_ the loop using various constructs like list comprehension, map, zip, recursion, and whatever else has been posted. __But all those still loop over the list `b`.__

Comment: @mhlester, SchighSchagh. I think it's clear OP means no _explicit_ looping; OP found cool behavior with `[1, 2]*2` and wants to know its limits.  What if the question was amended to say "Out of curiosity, can I ... without explicitly looping?"?

Comment: If OP had said that, it'd be fine. But as written currently, it says "I don't know how to loop, and I'm scared. I'm not ready to learn it yet so don't teach me the **right** way to do this."

Comment: @Bill I completely agree with mhlester. EDIT: Also, it's _not_ clear to me that OP simply means no _explicit_ looping, because I've seen questions here wherein posters seem to think that by hiding the loop, the code will magically run in _O(1)_ or something.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't mind a list of tuples, you could try some `zip` shenanigans:

```
zip(*zip(*b)*2)
```

which returns

```
[(1, 2, 1, 2), (3, 4, 3, 4)]
```

Comment: that is quite a splat of splats. **+1**

Answer (score 4):

Does a list comprehension count as looping?

```
>>> [x*2 for x in b]
[[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: It probably does, but there's no reason I can think of not to use one.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use loops, feel free to use recursion:

```
def expand(mylist,n):
    if len(mylist)==1:
        return [mylist[0]*n]
    else:
        return [mylist[0]*n] + expand(mylist[1:],n)
```

Input:

```
a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Call:

```
expand(a,2)
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4], [5, 6, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, iteration will happen no matter what if you want to solve the problem for arbitrary numbers of lists. If your list only has 2 members, the following solution works without iteration:

```
b = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
# Uses iterable unpacking, which may be considered iteration
l1, l2 = b
# If you don't want iterable unpacking, use that instead:
# l1 = b[0]; l2 = b[1]
print [l1 * 2, l2 * 2]
```

For an arbitrary number of lists and "hidden" iteration (you're iterating with the `map` function rather than with an explicit `for` loop), try this:

```
b = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
print map(lambda x: x * 2, b)
```

Comment: @mhlester Well, it is terrible taste but OP *asked* for no iteration. Of course I, too, would use a list comprehension or a `for` loop in the real world ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `map`:

```
>>> b = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> list(map(lambda l: l*2, b))
[[1, 2, 1, 2], [3, 4, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: This is the same as list comprehension, just much less readable.

Comment: That is kinda harsh. OP said 'no loops' and readability is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Well, now I'm too scared to post `list(map(list,map(chain.from_iterable,map(partial(repeat,times=2),b))))` even though it's entertaining, if people are going to downvote answers which arguably satisfy the (frankly silly) requirements.  [+1.]

Comment: @DSM, I'd **totally** upvote that, if only for the hilarity of the situation